# Apikit - status code best practices

Tags: mule

Using APIKit in Mule, I need to return a 404 status code if a particular resource is not found when executing my flow.

I can see three ways of handling this:

1. Throw a custom business exception(using a groovy script) i.e
       PersonNotFoundException and use the
       apikit:mapping-exception-strategy to map that exception to '404'
2. Throw the existing Mule exception
       org.mule.module.apikit.exception.NotFoundException which is already
       mapped to '404'
3. Do no throw an exception and manually set the http response and
       status code within the normal flow of my message.

What's the best practice here? Use exceptions for flow control? and if so use the Mule exception or a custom business exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is one of those weird combinations between API best practices and Mule best practices.

For generic resources, ie "/users" I would use the Mule Not Found Exception (404), but for an item resource that does not exist, ie "/users/jim-smith" for usability purposes I would throw a custom exception with "The user requested does not exist" or "You do not have permission to access this user" (status 401) whichever the case may be to best help developers utilizing your API.

I think the biggest advantage to the exception strategy instead of just manually changing the responses yourself is it creates a clear flow where you can easily determine what is a successful response, and what is a failed response.

That and using an exception handler within Mule you can return back a uniform error response to the user (in JSON, XML, etc).

But others might disagree with me, and just manually setting the status code and response yourself does offer the most flexibility, but also allows for inconsistencies.